# Update Statement Incorrectly Applying

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am trying to update 45000 rows with missing values on SQL Server 2000 sp4 Database.

I will try to simulate the table setup and conditions of values below:
I have two tables. One is holding valid transactions and the other has missing values in certain rows.

--Table #Trans holds valid transactions

```
Create Table #trans (
    [DocumentNumber] [char](21) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [char](21) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [char](31) NOT NULL,
    [ACTINDX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CRDTAMNT] [numeric](19, 5) NOT NULL,
    [DEBITAMT] [numeric](19, 5) NOT NULL,
    [TRXSORCE] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [TRXDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO #trans  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20123','Andrew Sesinyi','A0001',2501,25620.00,0.000,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20123','Andrew Sesinyi','A0001',2201,0.000,25620.00,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('PMTRN00155','Bame Moonwa','B0001',1700,1550.00,0.0000,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('PMTRN00155','Bame Moonwa','B0001',1900,0.0000,1550.00,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('PMTRN00156','OLERATO PHAMA','OL0001',1900,0.0000,1020.00,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('PMTRN00156','OLERATO PHAMA','OL0001',1700,1020.00,0.0000,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20124','Bame Moonwa','B0001',2501,18000.00,0.000,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #trans  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[TRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20124','Bame Moonwa','B0001',2201,0.000,18000.00,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
```

--Tables #GL holds some of the transactions with missing values i.e --DocumentNumber,CustomerID A and CustomerName

```
Create Table #GL(
    [DocumentNumber] [char](21) ,
    [CustomerName] [char](21),
    [CustomerID] [char](31),
    [ACTINDX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CRDTAMNT] [numeric](19, 5) NOT NULL,
    [DEBITAMT] [numeric](19, 5) NOT NULL,
    [ORTRXSORCE] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [TRXDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO #GL  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','Andrew Sesinyi','A0001',2501,25620.00,0.000,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','Andrew Sesinyi','A0001',2201,0.000,25620.00,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','Bame Moonwa','B0001',1700,1550.00,0.0000,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','Bame Moonwa','B0001',1900,0.0000,1550.00,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','','',1900,0.0000,1020.00,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('','','',1700,1020.00,0.0000,'PYMNTTRN17012015','17-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20124','','',2501,18000.00,0.000,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
INSERT INTO #GL  ([DocumentNumber],[CustomerName],[CustomerID],[ACTINDX],[CRDTAMNT],[DEBITAMT],[ORTRXSORCE],[TRXDATE])
Values('INV20124','','',2201,0.000,18000.00,'SALESTRN15012015','15-Jan-2015')
```

When I run the following update statement incorrect updates are rendered to the #GL Records. Is there an alternative method or better way to apply an update records in this scenario.

```
UPDATE #GL
SET DocumentNumber = TR.DocumentNumber
    , CustomerName = TR.CustomerName
    ,CustomerID =TR.CustomerID
FROM #GL GL
INNER JOIN #trans TR ON GL.ORTRXSORCE = TR.TRXSORCE
WHERE GL.ACTINDX = TR.ACTINDX
    AND GL.DEBITAMT = TR.DEBITAMT
    OR GL.CRDTAMNT = TR.CRDTAMNT
    AND GL.TRXDATE = TR.TRXDATE
```

N.B I am trying to use this method to update 45000 records that have missing values.
N.B Multiple transactions can be posted as a batch to the #GL hence the shared TRXSORCE

Many Thanks for your insight in advance.

Comment: What makes you think your query is updating incorrectly?

Comment: You may have ambiguity in your where clause. You're mixing ands and ors. Try explicitly wrapping logical statements together in parentheses. Also, FWIW, I personally would just add all that stuff in the where clause as part of the join conditions. Doesn't really matter, but it struck me as odd.

Comment: Hi David ,I have tested the resultset and compared the original values and the updated values.There is a mismatch.

Comment: UPDATE #GL
SET DocumentNumber = TR.DocumentNumber
 , CustomerName = TR.CustomerName
 ,CustomerID =TR.CustomerID
FROM #GL GL
INNER JOIN #trans TR ON GL.ORTRXSORCE = TR.TRXSORCE
WHERE GL.ACTINDX = TR.ACTINDX
 AND GL.DEBITAMT = TR.DEBITAMT
 AND GL.CRDTAMNT = TR.CRDTAMNT
 AND GL.TRXDATE = TR.TRXDATE

Comment: WorkIs on a small dataset I am yet to test on the 45000 rows.Thanks Xedni.

Comment: You are aware and is applied before or.  And you know you can insert values (..), (...), (..).

Answer (score 0):

I bet you mean

```
WHERE GL.ACTINDX = TR.ACTINDX
  AND (GL.DEBITAMT = TR.DEBITAMT OR GL.CRDTAMNT = TR.CRDTAMNT)
  AND GL.TRXDATE = TR.TRXDATE
```

Comment: I tried that Blam effects the same incorrect results as the 1st query.Thanks for your input.Replacing OR with AND gave me the correct results.